# In python what is a <type 'revision'>

Tags: python, svn

I am using pysvn to extract svn log information from subversion log history (Author, Date, Time, Revision). The code I am using below:

```
client = pysvn.Client()
client.callback_get_login 
commit_messages = client.log("url")
log_list = []
for i, commit in enumerate(commit_messages):
    rev = commit.revision
    auth = commit.author
    t = time.ctime(commit.date)
    mess = commit.message
    log_list.append(rev)
    log_list.append(auth)
    log_list.append(t)
    log_list.append(mess)
log_file = open("extracted_log_history",'wb')
wr = csv.writer(log_file, dialect = 'excel')
for item in log_list:
    wr.writerows(item)
```

I found that this could will not work returning the following `TypeError: writerows() argument must be iterable`. I believe it is not iterable because `rev = commit.revision` is returning a `<type 'revision'>` and the other variables (auth, t, mess) are all `<type 'str'>`. Any ideas on how I can get the revision number to be "iterable"?

Comment: `wr.writerows()` expects a list of rows. I'm sure you want to add just *one* row each iteration. But you also put your columns into separate rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<type 'revision'>` means you have a [`pysvn.Revision` instance](http://pysvn.stage.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html#pysvn_revision). If you wanted to write the revision number, use it's `revision.number` attribute.

However, your code has other issues. You are adding all the columns to `log_list` as separate rows, rather than as one column, and you are trying to write each row as a *sequence of rows* to the CSV. Don't use `csv.writerows()`, and write your rows *as you process the revisions*:

```
client = pysvn.Client()
client.callback_get_login
with open("extracted_log_history",'wb') as log_file:
    wr = csv.writer(log_file)
    for commit in client.log("url"):
        rev = commit.revision.number
        auth = commit.author
        t = time.ctime(commit.date)
        mess = commit.message
        row = [rev, auth, t, mess]
        wr.writerow(row)
```

Comment: I see what you are meaning. I appreciate the help and quick response. I am still an amateur with Python.